# ASP.NET MVC does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, pagination, paging, pagedlist

I am trying to insert Pagination feature into an Existing Application build by some other company. I am getting errors at cshtml:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<SQRL.PageModels.PageModelList<SQRL.ViewModels.LibraryViewModel>>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, PagedList.IPagedList, System.Func<int,string>)' has some invalid arguments

**Source Error:**

> Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<SQRL.PageModels.PageModelList<SQRL.ViewModels.LibraryViewModel>>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, PagedList.IPagedList, System.Func<int,string>)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

> @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
> new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int? managerGroupId, int? userGroupId, bool deletedBooks = false)
    {     
           var models = new LibraryViewModel[] { };
            models = Repository.LibrariesAsViewModels(managerGroup: managerGroupId, userGroup: userGroupId, includeInactive: deletedBooks)
                    .Where(p => p.ParentID.HasValue == false).OrderByDescending(p => p.SortOrder)
                    .Where(p => deletedBooks ? p.IsActive == false : true)
                    .ToArray();

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.currentFilter = currentFilter;
            int pageSize = 6;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        //    var model = new PageModelList<LibraryViewModel>();  **original code
        //    model.Items = models;  ** original code

            var modelnew = new PageModelList<LibraryViewModel>();
            modelnew.PList = models.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        // return view(model) **original code
            return View(modelnew);
}
```

**PageModelList:**

```
public class PageModelList<T> : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return Items.Count();
        }
    }

    public IPagedList<T> PList { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@model PageModelList<LibraryViewModel>

@*model PagedList.IPagedList<PageModelList<LibraryViewModel>>  --Commented out, there is error*@ 


<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        @*Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount*@

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the parameter of `@Html.PagedListPager` must be the type of `IPagedList` not the type `PageModelList`. you have to change this in your controller to return the model of type IPagedList and you also have to change `@model` statement in view also.

```
@model IPagedList<LibraryViewModel>
```